# When setting a link in a paragraph to "display: inline-block", then selecting/highlighting the entire paragraph, a little block appears over the link?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/3LxRr/

When highlighting a paragraph containing a link that's set to "display:inline-block", there appears a little white block over the top of the link ( when it's selected/highlighted). press Ctrl+A to select everything on the page and you'll see what the problem is.

If I change the line-height down to 16px - it goes away, but the line-height for the paragraph and the link are the same. I need the link to be displayed as an inline-block because I have tool tips that pop up, and if the link gets split in half by a new line, the tool tip appears in the middle of the page, so inline-block is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only happens in webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari). It's something about how the browser engine renders text selection highlight and is not really a CSS issue. because when you apply background color your code will [work same in every browser.](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/3LxRr/3/)

If you believe it's a bug you can report it to [webkit.org](http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html)

[image]

Comment: K so we've discovered that the little block above the link is actually an area where the selection/highlighting hasn't covered/highlighted, it left it out of the highlight.. I still want to see if there's a way to fix this.